# Unexpected output when combining expand_grid with do.call / lift_dl

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

When using tidyr::expand_grid in combination with do.call (or lift_dl) the output is not the same compared to a direct call of the function with multiple (tibble) elements.

Expected:

```
dat <- list(tibble(a = 1:2), NULL, tibble(b = 2))
tidyr::expand_grid(dat[[1]], dat[[2]], dat[[3]], .name_repair = "minimal")
```

Different result when using do.call or lift_dl:

```
do.call(tidyr::expand_grid, c(dat, list(.name_repair = "minimal"))) # version do.call
purrr::lift_dl(expand_grid)(dat, .name_repair = "minimal") # version lift_dl
```

Using latest tidyr on cran (1.1.0)

Any ideas why?